# Loop break breaking tqdm

Tags: python, tqdm

The following simple code uses [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) to display a progress bar while iterating over a loop:

```
import tqdm
for f in tqdm.tqdm(range(100000000)):
  if f > 100000000/4:
    break
```

It fails when the break is executed:

```
$ python test.py 
 24%|████▎ | 24425076/100000000 [00:03<00:11, 6550673.18it/s]
Exception KeyError: KeyError(<weakref at 0x7fb8799f1158; to 'tqdm' at 0x7fb8799de190>,) in  ignored
```

I am using Python v2.7.6, and tqdm v4.32.1:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python -m tqdm --version
4.23.1
```

I looked for similar errors on the Internet with no positive outcome.

Comment: I don't use the library but it looks like you're deliberately breaking out at 25%? How should a progress bar respond to that?

Comment: I was trying to use tqdm in a loop that can stop when a given condition is true.

Comment: @roganjosh when an error occurs you might want to update or abandon the progress bar without other errors occurring that might confuse the following logic or messages provided to the user.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It turns out the *tqdm* iterator has to be closed manually when it is interrupted:

```
import tqdm
iterator = tqdm.tqdm(range(100000000))
for f in iterator:
  if f > 100000000/4:
    iterator.close()
    break
```

This executes without problems.