# tqdm color bar shows red if using break in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I use `tqdm` from `tqdm.notebook` to display a progress bar for iteration through lines of a file. I supply the `total` argument to give the number of iterations that will be performed (since I know it upfront) so the progress can be accurately displayed.

I use a `break` to stop at the maximum number of desired iterations (lines of the file to read).

Despite the fact that the number of iterations performed is equal to the value supplied to `total` in `tqdm` and the progress bar shows the maximum number of iterations have been performed (e.g. 11/11 in the example; see image), the bar is displayed in red (not green) indicating premature termination / an error.

I have already tried to assign the tqdm object to a variable and explicitly close the iterator in the condition before the break as per [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017481/loop-break-breaking-tqdm).

How can I make the progress bar display correctly?

```py
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
LETTERS = list('ABCDEFGHIJKL')
for idx, letter in enumerate(tqdm(LETTERS, total=len(LETTERS)-1)):
    print(letter)
    if idx >= len(LETTERS) - 1:
        break
```

[image]

---

Version information (if helpful)

IPython          : 8.1.1
ipykernel        : 6.9.2
ipywidgets       : 7.7.0
jupyter_client   : 7.1.2
jupyter_core     : 4.9.2
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.5.13
nbconvert        : 6.4.4
nbformat         : 5.2.0
notebook         : 6.4.10
qtconsole        : 5.2.2
traitlets        : 5.1.1

Running with Python 3.8.10.

Comment: Why would you use break in this case instead of just letting the loop come to an end?

Comment: @aaossa The use case is iterating through a file and stopping before the total number of lines via `break`. Subsetting is not possible on a `TextIOWrapper` object (i.e. the type of `open(fname)`) so the break is used necessarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `break` is in the last iteration, `tqdm` assumes that the loop stopped unintendedly, even if the loop is finished from the semantic side.

If you want to have a green progress bar in the end structure your code like this

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

LETTERS = list('ABCDEFGHIJKL')
for idx, letter in enumerate(tqdm(LETTERS, total=len(LETTERS))):
    if idx == len(LETTERS):
        break
    print(letter)
```

Comment: By "structure your code like this" you mean specifying total and making actual iterations # equal to it? What if break happens on some condition and iterations # is unknown in advance, do you know the solution then?

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev Showing a progress bar with an unknown number of iterations is a difficult problem, maybe you can do an initial guess here... when you know the exact number, you can adjust it with pbar.total = final_number and close ist with pbar.close()